# How would I make my random number appear instantly on my frame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

```
JTextField RandomNumber = new JTextField(30);
//Code for randum number below.
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 1;
RandomNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                       

    //Code for function goes here.  
    Random rn = new Random();
    RandomNumber.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt(51))); 


    }}); 
p2.add(RandomNumber, gbc); //Adding to the panel, after done with all functions.
```

My goal is to make the randomly generated number appear along with when the frame is opened. As far as now, the randomly generated number will only appear if I press my enter key on the JTextField RandomNumber.So my question is how would I make the random number appear inside the textfield without having to press any keys on my keyboard. Thanks! And apologies for the novice-level question!

Comment: Just move it outside of the `ActionListener`. (??) I'm not really sure if you mean something else though.

Comment: Don't put it in the `ActionListener`. The `ActionListener` is listening for you to hit enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have your random number appear at the start of execution, put it outside of the action listener. The action listener will **only** execute when an action is triggered (hitting enter, etc).

Also i would suggest to try renaming your variables and make the first letter start with a lowercase. You can see Java naming conventions for variables [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

```
JTextField randomNumberTextField= new JTextField(30);
//Code for randum number below.
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 1;
randomNumberTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                      

           // Code to execute when you hit enter


    }}); 

//Code for function goes here.  
Random rn = new Random();
randomNumberTextField.setText(Integer.toString(rn.nextInt(51)));
p2.add(randomNumberTextField, gbc); //Adding to the panel, after done with all functions.
```